# Error in Gated Check In Build Definition Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, msbuild, tfsbuild

Could any one solve this problem?

I have the same error, running Build Definition "Gated Check-in" in Visual Studio 2013.

I created a Build Definition, selected the Gated Ckeck-In trigger. I have disabled almost everything, Automated tests, Clean Workspace, and I keep seeing the following error message:

> Other Errors and Warnings
>    1 error(s), 0 warning(s)
>    Exception Message: MSBuild error 1 has ended this build. You can find more specific information about the cause of this error in above messages. (type BuildProcessTerminateException)
>   Exception Stack Trace:    at System.Activities.Statements.Throw.Execute(CodeActivityContext context)
>      at System.Activities.CodeActivity.InternalExecute(ActivityInstance instance, ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager)
>      at System.Activities.Runtime.ActivityExecutor.ExecuteActivityWorkItem.ExecuteBody(ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager, Location resultLocation)

Has anyone already solved it?

Cheers!

Comment: It says that MsBuild itself failed. So there must be something wrong with the solution or one of its dependencies or with the way Team Build changes the output structure.

Comment: I think it is not the solution, when doing a Buil manually (Ctrl + Shift + B) it works perfectly, it must be the way Team Build works but, that's the thing, I don't know what is going wrong...

Would be helpful if I upload something else that could give us a clue where the error is?

Comment: Also, I have no TFS installed fisically anywhere, all is working with Visual Studio 2013 Online Ultimate

Answer (score 0):

I found what it is, at least in my case.

When I make my build fail intentionally (missing a ; for instance) it throws this first error (missing ; at line #) and the general error: MSBuild error 1 has ended  this build. You can find more specific information about the cause of this error in **above messages**.

I didn't put much attention in that message. So if an error is found in my build, automatically it throws that MSBuild error, otherwise it succeed perfectly well.